# XSLT Consolidating data when ID is the same

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having some issues with consuming an XML and applying multiple conditions on it. I have an input XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ResultsType">
    <result>
        <resultSets>
            <resultSet>
                <row>
                    <column1>11111</column1>
                    <column2>0</column2>
                    <column3>imageId/111111</column3>
                    <column4>2012-04-03T10:11:22.187</column4>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <column1>11111</column1>
                    <column2>2</column2>
                    <column3>imageId/111112</column3>
                    <column4>2012-04-03T10:11:22.187</column4>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <column1>11111</column1>
                    <column2>2</column2>
                    <column3>imageId/111113</column3>
                    <column4>2012-04-03T10:11:22.187</column4>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <column1>22222</column1>
                    <column2>0</column2>
                    <column3>imageId/222222</column3>
                    <column4>2012-04-03T10:11:22.187</column4>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <column1>22222</column1>
                    <column2>2</column2>
                    <column3>imageId/222223</column3>
                    <column4>2012-04-03T10:11:22.187</column4>
                </row>
            </resultSet>
        </resultSets>
    </result>
</results>
```

However i would like it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ResultsType">
    <result>
        <row>
            <id>11111</id>
            <lagrgeImage>imageId/111111</lagrgeImage>
            <smallImage>imageId/111112</smallImage>
            <smallImage>imageId/111113</smallImage>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>22222</id>
            <lagrgeImage>imageId/222222</lagrgeImage>
            <smallImage>imageId/222223</smallImage>
        </row>
    </result>
</results>
```

As you can see there are two filtering condition:

If column2 = 0 then largeImage tag is needed in the output however column2 = 2 then smallImage tag is needed in the output.

**UPDATE**

Both of the examples below worked perfectly, however they are both including namespacing in the root that are unexpected. The output i get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ResultsType">
    <result>
        <row>
            <id>11111</id>
            <largeImage>imageId/111111</largeImage>
            <smallImage>imageId/111112</smallImage>
            <smallImage>imageId/111113</smallImage>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>22222</id>
            <largeImage>imageId/222222</largeImage>
            <smallImage>imageId/222223</smallImage>
        </row>
    </result>
</results>
```

How do i remove `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ResultsType"` from the above output?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2.0 as this has dedicated commands for grouping.

Comment: XSLT2.0....I can for loop around however the bit i dont know how to do it to get the XSLT to know what was the ID in the last loop. If the id is the same as the one before at to the already created tag...if not add a new tag with the new id. How do you do this?

Comment: @liveek: I have added a solution (which is even XSLT 1.0 compatiable) that runs a for-each loop once for each ID.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper this was the bit i did not know how to do `preceding-sibling::` thanks

Comment: @liveek: Glad to hear that :-) Please mark the solution as accepted if you have no further questions left, or otherwise write a comment below my solution so I'll notice if you need any further info :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XSLT2.0 you make use of the **for-each-group** function.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="column1">
```

Assuming your context is **resultSets** this would group the rows by the 'id' in **column1**. The current grouping key could then be obtained as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
```

And to get the various rows in the group, to transform them to either largeImage or smallImage, you would do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.castiron.com//response">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="resultSets">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="resultSet">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="column1">
         <row>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
          </row>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row[column2='0']">
      <largeImage><xsl:value-of select="column3" /></largeImage>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <smallImage><xsl:value-of select="column3" /></smallImage>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
      <xsl:copy> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<results xmlns="http://www.castiron.com//response">
   <result>
      <row>
         <id>11111</id>
         <largeImage>imageId/111111</largeImage>
         <smallImage>imageId/111112</smallImage>
         <smallImage>imageId/111113</smallImage>
      </row>
      <row>
         <id>22222</id>
         <largeImage>imageId/222222</largeImage>
         <smallImage>imageId/222223</smallImage>
      </row>
   </result>
</results>
```

Comment: This works perfectly; however i am getting the following namespacing in the root node `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ResultsType"` is there a way to remove it? Root Node: `<imageScene7Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com//response" (This is needed) xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" (Not needed) xsi:type="ResultsType" (Not needed)>`

Comment: I did exclude the namespace from my input sample, to keep it simple. Can you amend the question though, to show the expected output with the new root node and namespace, and I will see if I can amend my answer.

Comment: I've made an amendment to remove the old namespace and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

For spitting out the 'largeimage' and 'smallimage' elements (in an xsl for loop) try:

> ```
> <xsl:if test="/results/result/resultSets/resultSet/row/column2='0'">
> <largeImage>
> <xsl:value-of select="/results/result/resultSets/resultSet/row/column3"/>
> </largeImage>    
> </xsl:if>
> ```

Comment: How do you join multiple IDs together. I get the for loop, loop through every ID however how do i add it to the previous if the same id was the one before? Does that make sense?

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=548449

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, the (IMO) most straightforward solution is to first find all unique IDs. This can be achieved by looking for IDs that did not appear in any preceding siblings (in other words, for each ID, you find the first element that contains that ID).

Once you have a unique ID, you can `<xsl:for-each>` over all `<row>` siblings (including the current element) with the same ID. In the below code, I have used an `<xsl:choose>` element to check `<column2>` and insert a `<largeImage>` or `<smallImage>` element based on the `<column2>` value.

This does what you are looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/results">
        <results>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <result>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result"/>
            </result>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/results/result/resultSets/resultSet/row">
        <xsl:if test="not(column1 = preceding-sibling::row/column1)">
            <row>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="column1"/></id>
                <xsl:for-each select="../row[column1 = current()/column1]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="column2 = '0'">
                            <largeImage><xsl:value-of select="column3"/></largeImage>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="column2 = '2'">
                            <smallImage><xsl:value-of select="column3"/></smallImage>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works perfectly; however i am getting the following namespacing in the root node `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ResultsType"` is there a way to remove it? Root Node: `<imageScene7Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com//response" (This is needed) xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" (Not needed) xsi:type="ResultsType" (Not needed)>`

Comment: Just omit the line `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` from the XSLT. That line is responsible for copying the attributes of the `<results>` element.