# Stuck on grouping in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have an input file like this

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>Harry</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <color>blue</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>Harry</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>Harry</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <is_single>true</is_single>
    </item>
</items>
```

I'd like to group up the elements so that the file looks like this

```
<items>
<item>
    <id>5</id>
    <name>Harry</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <color>blue</color>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <is_single>true</is_single>
</item>
</items>
```

EDIT - Made an XSLT transform following this link ([XSLT Consolidating data when ID is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247326/xslt-consolidating-data-when-id-is-the-same)) but this just doesn't print anything.

Here is my transform (using XSLT 2.0) -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="id">
    <item>
        <id><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
    </item>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use `for-each-group` - check out the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11247326/1395993), which is a similar problem.

Comment: Grouping is so different in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, you really need to say which you are using.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to state this before, I'm using XSLT 2.0, and I updated my question with the XSLT transform I have now.

Comment: The `for-each-group` should be in the context of `items`, not `item` - it can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is you have a template matching the **item** element:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
```

But within this, you have an **xsl:for-each-group** that also looks for **item** elements

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="id">
```

What this means is that you are looking for **item** elements that are children of other **item** elements, of which there are none in the XML. I think you need to combine the first two templates into one here:

```
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="id">
        <item>
           ....
```

One thing that is not clear is what elements within **item** elements will be repeated. Will it always be the id, name and age? It's probably best to be flexible here though, and assume only **id** will be the common element. I will also assume if two elements are repeated (like **name**) it will always have the same value.

So, to get all the other distinct non-id elements, you could some more grouping on element name

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*[not(self::id)]" group-by="local-name()">
```

Then, within this loop you can just output the element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="id">
    <item>
      <id><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></id>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*[not(self::id)]" group-by="local-name()">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </item>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<item>
   <id>5</id>
   <name>Harry</name>
   <age>18</age>
   <color>blue</color>
   <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
   <is_single>true</is_single>
</item>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot and I appreciate the detailed explanation!