# Consolidation of Data using certain keys in XSLT

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have an input XML file:

```
<root>
   <row>
     <col1>cust001</col1>
     <col2>cc1</col2>
     <col3>po1</col3>
     <col4>2020-02-22</col4>
     <col5>Men</col5>
     <col6>item1</col6>
     <col7>60</col7>
   </row>
   <row>
     <col1>cust001</col1>
     <col2>cc1</col2>
     <col3>po1</col3>
     <col4>2020-02-22</col4>
     <col5>Men</col5>
     <col6>item2</col6>
     <col7>50</col7>
   </row>
</root>
```

Desired output: (if col1 to col5 are the same, consolidate into one row.)

```
<root>
       <row>
         <col1>cust001</col1>
         <col2>cc1</col2>
         <col3>po1</col3>
         <col4>2020-02-22</col4>
         <col5>Men</col5>
         <col6>item1</col6>
         <col7>60</col7>
         <col6>item2</col6>
         <col7>50</col7>
       </row>
    </root>
```

I'm trying the code here [XSLT Consolidating data when ID is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247326/xslt-consolidating-data-when-id-is-the-same) but I'm getting, Error in Expression current-group(): Unknown system function: current group.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.castiron.com//response">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="resultSets">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="resultSet">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="root/row" group-by="concat(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)">            
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />            
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you trying to use for a question tagged as XSLT 3? Use Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 or AltovaXML 2017 R3 or later (make sure for them you set `version="3.0"` in your XSLT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later or AltovaXML 2017 R3 or later you can use a composite grouping key of the elements you want to use as a grouping key, then, inside, you of course need to make sure you create a single `row` for each group and only process the items forming the grouping key once (e.g. for the first item in the group which is the context item inside of the `for-each-group`) and then all the other elements for all items in the group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="row" composite="yes" group-by="col1, col2, col3, col4, col5">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, current-group()/(* except (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5))"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1yt

Or, perhaps, the body of the `for-each-group` is a bit less repetitive in terms of the grouping key elements with

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row!copy-of()" composite="yes" group-by="col1, col2, col3, col4, col5">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/(if (position() eq 1) then * else (* except (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)))"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1yt/1